# PHP Get all files but not in subdirectories

Tags: php, recursion, iterator

Im using this code:

```
$path = realpath('');
$i = 0;
$objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path));

foreach($objects as $name => $object){
```

and it gets all sub directories in the main directory, when I only want it to get in the current directory

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: [scandir()](http://se2.php.net/scandir) may be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of [`glob()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) instead.

```
<?php
chdir('yourcurrentdirectory');
foreach(glob("*.*") as $file)
{
  echo $files."<br>";
}
```

Comment: That did the job. Thanks.